# Zend Framework : Form_MyForm not found in blah... Is this a BOOTSTRAP issue?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, bootstrapping

I am a newbie, and getting this error:
 - **Fatal error:** Class 'Form_UploadBom' not found in **C:\wamp\NetBeansProjects\bomSlave\application\controllers\BomController.php** on line **18**
What am I missing ??
What am I doing wrong??

As you'd expect, line 18 of *BomController.php* is where I call for an instance of my form.

```
17.    public function uploadAction()   {
18.       $form = new Form_UploadBom();
19.       $this->view->form = $form;
20.    }
```

My form is at *//application/forms/uploadbom.phtml*

```
class Form_UploadBom extends Zend_Form {
    public function __construct($option = null) {
        parent::__construct($option);

        $this->setName('bomupload');

        $company = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('co');
        $company->setLabel('Cust Company:')
                ->setRequired(); 

        $contact = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('contact');
        $contact->setLabel('Cust Contact')
                ->setRequired(); 

        $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('bom');
        $file->setLabel('BOM File (in CSV):')
                ->setRequired(); 

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Uplaod BOM');

        $this->addElements(array(  $company, $contact, $file, $submit  ));
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAction('');
    }
}
```

And here's the Auto Loader from my *Bootstrap* file

```
protected function _initAutoLoad(){
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'resourceTypes' => array (
            'model' => array(
                'path' => 'models/',
                'namespace' => 'Model_',
                ),
            'form' => array(
                'path' => 'forms/',
                'namespace' => 'Form_',
                )
            )
        )
    );       
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Again, what am I missing ??
What am I doing wrong??
(and *please* don't tell me it's just a type-o somewhere ... 
...that would just be embarrassing :)

~ Mo

[[EDIT]]
Well, after changing the file extension from phtml to php, that error is gone ... but ... I now have an error about view helpers.
 - **Warning:** Missing argument 1 for Zend_View_Helper_Form::form() ....
And this notice:
 - **Notice:*** Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\bin\php\ZendFramework\1.11.11\library\Zend\View\Helper\Form.php on line 46

How does all that come into play ??

[[/EDIT]]

Comment: Typically, the code to add elements to the form resides in the form's `init()` method, instead of in the constructor. Shouldn't matter, since your constructor calls the parent constructor, but worth a try anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, after changing the file extension from phtml to php, that error
>   is gone ... but ... I now have an error about view helpers.
>   - Warning: Missing argument 1 for Zend_View_Helper_Form::form() .... And this notice:
>   - Notice:* Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\bin\php\ZendFramework\1.11.11\library\Zend\View\Helper\Form.php
>   on line 46
>
> How does all that come into play ??

I've noticed a few issues that may affect this problem.

1. Zend_Form_Element_File requires that the form encoding be:

   `$form->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');`
2. Zend_Form_Element_File needs a destination set
    `$element->setDestination('/var/www/upload');`
3. `->setRequired()` is False by default, I'm pretty sure you need to actually flag it as true to make an element required. `$element->setRquired('TRUE');`
4. Common usage of forms extending Zend_Form is to build the form in the `init()` method, it is not technically wrong to do it in `__construct()`. It's just that Zend_Form specifically sets `init()` aside for this purpose.

Number 3 and 4 should not have anything to do with your viewhelper issue, 1 and 2 likely will.

Also an observation... 
If you are using the current version of ZF (1.11) your `_initAutoload()` in your bootstrap is largely unnecessary as forms and models have default routes and you're really not changing them.
The only change you would have to make to use the default routes would be to make sure your appNamespace is the first word of the classname. In normal default usage that would be 'Application'... so `Form_UploadBom()` would become `Application_Form_UploadBom()`.
 I realize you may have done this fully informed and on purpose and are not just following some out of date book or tutorial. If so... code on :)

Comment: Extremely helpful. Including your "Also an Observation...". Thank you for the comprehensive details. Thank you for the gentle wording. On all count, thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

The `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` replaces `_` with `/` to find the form `Form_UploadBom` at the path `application/forms/UploadBom.php`.

Change the file name of your form to

```
/application/forms/UploadBom.php
```

The file extension `.phtml` is only used for view related stuff.

Comment: Thanks .. renaming the extension was the first step I took.
It made a big difference, but I now have another error about View Helpers. Why is it talking about view helpers ???? I don't see how I've roped that into the mess. ((See the edit in to OP. I'll post an update there.))